# How to provide values to a template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using the XCeed Extended Toolkit Plus. The charting specifically. However, I don't think question need to be specifically about this control, more about how to pass or share values between controls and templates.

The charts are in a WPF UserControl, but the values are set in the code behind. There is no data binding or MVVM, more of a 'winforms' approach.

The charting works, but I want to alter the way the bar's (in a bar graph) display.

According to the documentation, I can use a Template

```
<xctk:Chart >
            <xctk:Chart.Areas>
                <xctk:Area x:Name="MyGraphArea">
                    <xctk:Area.XAxis>

                        <xctk:Axis Title="Date" 
                                   />
                    </xctk:Area.XAxis>
                    <xctk:Area.YAxis>
                        <xctk:Axis Title="Position"  
                                   />
                    </xctk:Area.YAxis>
                    <xctk:Area.Series>
                        <xctk:Series Template="{StaticResource SeriesTemplate}" >
                            <!--done in code behind-->
                        </xctk:Series>
                    </xctk:Area.Series>
                </xctk:Area>
            </xctk:Chart.Areas>
        </xctk:Chart>
```

On the same XAML page, I also have in my `Grid.Resources`. This is where the **problem** is

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="SeriesTemplate">
            <Button x:Name="Bar">
                <StackPanel>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="seriesTemplateDate" Text="How To I Bind"></TextBlock>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="seriesTemplatePosition" Text="What Am I binding too"></TextBlock>
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And in my code behind (showing constructor)

```
    public GraphView(IEnumerable<DataPoint> graphData, string title)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var series = new Series();

        foreach (var dataPoint in graphData)
        {
            series.DataPoints.Add(dataPoint);
        }
        series.Title = title;

        this.MyGraphArea.Series.Add(series);
    }
```

So, the DataTemplate is where I'm having an issue. I have no idea what to enter the for `text` value

I don't think I can add the value by name and set it in the code behind because it gets called on each iteration (depending on how many items are in the series).

The only way, in my head, is if it the DataTemplate can inherit some how from the calling control. At this stage, my Google results were providing nothing useful, and I think I'm getting myself muddled!

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess since I do not know the XCeed Extended Toolkit Plus. That being said, the Datacontext of a Datatemplate is usually set to the data object. In this case that should be the series object. This means you can bind directly to properties on the series object like the Title-property. Maybe it also has a Date and Position property?!

```
series.Title = title;
series.Date = date;
series.Position = position;

<TextBlock x:Name="seriesTemplateTitle" Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Name="seriesTemplateDate" Text="{Binding Date}"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Name="seriesTemplatePosition" Text="{Binding Position}"></TextBlock>
```

Good Luck!